# JavaFX thread is hanging when using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, executorservice

I'm trying to write a program that uses Imgur's API to download images based on an account name.

```
private volatile int threadCount;
private volatile double totalFileSize;
private volatile List<String> albums = new ArrayList<>();
private volatile Map<JSONObject, String> images = new HashMap<>();

private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100, (Runnable r) -> {
        Thread t = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t;
    });

private void downloadAlbums(List<String> albums) {
    threadCount = 0;
    albums.forEach((albumHash) -> {
        if (hasRemainingRequests()) {
            incThreadCount();
            executorService.execute(() -> {
                try {
                    String responseString;
                    String dirTitle;
                    String albumUrl = URL_ALBUM + albumHash;
                    String query = String.format("client_id=%s", URLEncoder.encode(CLIENT_ID, CHARSET));
                    URLConnection connection = new URL(albumUrl + "?" + query).openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", CHARSET);
                    InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();

                    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(response)) {
                        responseString = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseString).getJSONObject("data");
                        dirTitle = obj.getString("title");
                        String temp = "";

                        // Get save path from a TextField somewhere else on the GUI
                        ObservableList<Node> nodes = primaryStage.getScene().getRoot().getChildrenUnmodifiable();
                        for (Node node : nodes) {
                            if (node instanceof VBox) {
                                ObservableList<Node> vNodes = ((VBox) node).getChildrenUnmodifiable();
                                for (Node vNode : vNodes) {
                                    if (vNode instanceof DestinationBrowser) {
                                        temp = ((DestinationBrowser) vNode).getDestination().trim();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        final String path = temp + "\\" + formatPath(accountName) + "\\" + formatPath(dirTitle);
                        JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("images");
                        arr.forEach((jsonObject) -> {
                            totalFileSize += ((JSONObject) jsonObject).getDouble("size");
                            images.put((JSONObject) jsonObject, path);
                        });
                    }

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    //
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    //
                } finally {
                    decThreadCount();
                    if (threadCount == 0) {
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {

                            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
                            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);//                      714833218
                            alert.setHeaderText("Found " + images.size() + " images (" + (totalFileSize < 1000000000 ? df.format(totalFileSize / 1000000) + " MB)" : df.format(totalFileSize / 1000000000) + " GB)"));
                            alert.setContentText("Proceed with download and save images?");
                            Optional<ButtonType> alertResponse = alert.showAndWait();

                            if (alertResponse.get() == ButtonType.OK) {
                                progressBar.setTotalWork(images.size());
                                executorService.execute(() -> {
                                    for (JSONObject obj : images.keySet()) {
                                        (new File(images.get(obj))).mkdirs();
                                        downloadImage(obj, images.get(obj));
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

`albums` is a List of codes that are required to send a GET request to Imgur in order to receive that album's images. The data returned is then used in another method which downloads the images themselves. 
Now, all of this works fine, but when the program is making all the GET requests the JavaFX thread hangs (GUI becomes unresponsive). And after all the GET requests have been executed, the JavaFX thread stops hanging and the `alert` shows up with the correct information.
I just don't understand why the GUI becomes unresponsive when I'm not (I believe I'm not) blocking it's thread and I'm using an `ExecutorService` to do all the network requests.

Comment: How is `hasRemainingRequests()` implemented? BTW: there are several issues with your implementation: Making `images` `volatile` only makes sure a replacement of the reference is visible to other threads. There's no guarantee that the `HashMap` itself is consistent for the threads. Also you read from the the GUI on background threads. Accessing the GUI like this can lead to unexpected results including exceptions. Furthermore 100 is a huge number of threads, especially since they seem to access the same resource (your internet connection).

Comment: `incThreadCount()`/`decThreadCount()` could also be an issue and I recommend using `AtomicInteger`

Comment: @fabian `hasRemainingRequests()` sends a requests to the Imgur API, who responds with how many requests the user (IP based) and the client (CLIENT_ID based) are still allowed to make before access to the API is blocked.

Comment: 100 threads is indeed a huge number.  I wouldn’t be surprised if you are simply starving the JavaFX application thread of CPU time.

Comment: @fabian I tested this with lower thread counts as well (4-8), but the hanging kept occuring.